# Cmake compilation of HipHop PHP fails

Tags: centos, php

I followed this tutorial to try to install hiphop php in CentOS: 
http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/04/22/howto-install-hiphop-for-php-on-centos-5-x/comment-page-1/#comment-416

Instead git-cloning the main branch I cloned the "vm" branch, which is most recent. In theory, it should work.

The problem is in the last steps, when I bootstrap "boost" for example, I got a lot errors and it takes a lot of time to finish (about 4 hours) with this:
…failed updating 6 targets…
…skipped 12 targets…
…updated 9122 targets…

Seems to be usable, so i continued until the last step:

```
cd hiphop-php
git submodule init
git submodule update
export HPHP_HOME=`pwd`
export HPHP_LIB=`pwd`/bin
cmake .
```

Here is where the problem comes:

```
– CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
– MySQL Include dir: /usr/include library dir: /usr/lib64/mysql
– MySQL client libraries: mysqlclient_r
– Found libevent: /root/hiphop/local/lib/libevent.so
– Found GD: /usr/lib64/libgd.so
– Found ICU header files in /root/hiphop/local/include
– Found ICU libraries: /root/hiphop/local/lib/libicuuc.so
– Can’t find jemalloc
– Can’t find minimal tcmalloc
– Found Intel TBB
– Found mcrypt: /usr/lib64/libmcrypt.so
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:57 (MESSAGE):
Could NOT find LibElf (missing: LIBELF_LIBRARIES LIBELF_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMake/FindLibElf.cmake:50 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
CMake/FindLibDwarf.cmake:12 (find_package)
CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:250 (find_package)
CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:46 (include)
src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)

– Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I don't understand why "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway" if I already set the variables in the right directory with:

```
export CC=gcc44
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`pwd`/local
```

Maybe I have to clean first before retrying to build again, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I built HipHop earlier this week on Ubuntu, so hopefully I can give you some pointers. (My experience, for Ubuntu people: http://societyofcode.com/articles/guide_getting_started_with_hiphop_for_php-01-04-12)

-The "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" was missing message is meaningless, from what I can tell. It shows up even on a successful compile.

-I used the main branch, and am not sure of the stability of vm. It's probably worth a shot to clone main as well, just as a resort.

-Make sure you delete the CMakeCache.txt file in the directory. Do that and try again.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried again with the main branch and cmake didn't throw any errors. So it seems that the vm branch is not stable yet or is a little more tricky to install :(

Comment: Alright, that answers that question then. I looked into the vm branch and it was started recently (December 8th) and has no real changes from the master branch (aside from some deletions in the MakeFile and other areas), so you should be safe using the main one for the time being.

Comment: I kept trying to install the “vm” branch and resolved the cmake errors by installing manually the libelf & libdwarf libraries. But after some hours running make:

`code`[ 63%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/hphp_runtime_static.dir/system/gen/sys/dynamic_table_func.no.cpp.o
g++44: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See for instructions.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/hphp_runtime_static.dir/system/gen/sys/dynamic_table_func.no.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/hphp_runtime_static.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2 `code`